# Loading and sharing configuration data in an Akka project

Tags: java, design-patterns, akka, typesafe-config

I’ve defined two application.conf files, one for each environment, namely dev and prod :

```
application-dev.conf
application-prod.conf
```

To read the configuration values I use a config object builder (using lombok) named `ConfigurationObject` to set the values read from the application configuration files. The configuration object just stores two properties ‘kafkaBrokers’ and ‘someOtherConfig’ :

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ConfigLoader {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigLoader.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String env = "dev";
        final Config configDev = ConfigFactory.load("application-"+env+".conf");
        final ConfigurationObject configurationObjectDev = ConfigurationObject.builder()
                .kafkaBrokers(configDev.getString("kafka-config.brokers"))
                .someOtherConfig(configDev.getString("kafka-config.brokers"))
                .build();

        env = "prod";
        final Config configProd = ConfigFactory.load("application-"+env+".conf");
        final ConfigurationObject configurationObjectProd = ConfigurationObject.builder()
                .kafkaBrokers(configProd.getString("kafka-config.brokers"))
                .someOtherConfig(configProd.getString("kafka-config.brokers"))
                .build();

        LOGGER.info(configurationObjectDev.toString());
        LOGGER.info(configurationObjectProd.toString());

    }
}
```

Here I’ve defined the configuration object to store the values read from application.conf :

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.ToString;

@Builder
@ToString
public class ConfigurationObject {
    final String kafkaBrokers;
    final String someOtherConfig;
}
```

Should I just use ConfigFactory.load directly instead of wrapping each property from a given environment application.conf to a configuration object, in this case ConfigLoader. Is there a pattern I should use for this ?

Application conf files :

application-dev.conf :

```
kafka-config {
    brokers="broker1,broker4"
    brokers = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
}

some-other-config {
    brokers="broker-prod1,broker-prod4"
    brokers = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
}
```

application-prod.conf :

```
kafka-config {
    brokers="broker-prod1,broker-prod4"
}
some-other-config {
    brokers="broker-prod1,broker-prod4"
   brokers = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not an uncommon pattern in Lightbend Config/HOCON to define a class representing your application's configuration.  On the Scala side, there are tools like PureConfig which make it easy to read a config into such a class.  I'm not aware of similar tools on the Java side (e.g. which reflectively look at the configuration class and let you build an instance of that class from the `Config` object, inferring the schema along the way), but I don't think such tools are impossible.

Whether or not you're defining such a class, it's generally a good idea to have one and only one load of config in an application and then pass either the class you defined to represent the configuration or the `Config` object around: file/resource I/O and parsing is not free and multiple loads can add cognitive load.

I'm a little dubious on reading both `application-dev.conf` and `application-prod.conf`.  If your application needs both sets of Kafka brokers (e.g. it's consuming from one and producing to the other), then it might be worth having (e.g.) a `source-kafka` and `destination-kafka` config stanza in a single config file.  Alternatively, if your application will only in practice be using one config, you can specify the `config.file` property (e.g. by adding `-Dconfig.file=application-dev.conf` on the Java command line) and then just use `ConfigFactory.load()`.  In such cases, it may be a good idea to combine config files via HOCON's file inclusion capability.  This is often used to define an overrides config file with deployment-/environment-specific config which includes the regular `application.conf` which combines more universal settings.